# Dropout: why is my neural network not working?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm using normalized MNIST dataset (input features = `784`). My network architecture is `784-256-256-10`: two hidden layers of 256 neurons each using sigmoid activation functions, and softmax activation at 10-neuron output layer. Also I'm using the Cross-Entropy cost function.

Weight matrix initialization:

```
input_size=784
hidden1_size=256
hidden2_size=256
output_size=10
Theta1 = np.random.randn(hidden1_size, input_size)
b1 = np.random.randn(hidden1_size)

Theta2 = np.random.randn(hidden2_size, hidden1_size)
b2 = np.random.randn(hidden2_size)

Theta3 = np.random.randn(output_size, hidden2_size)
b3 = np.random.randn(output_size)
```

My network works as expected here:

```
epochs = 2000
learning_rate = 0.01
for j in range(epochs):
    # total_train is an array of length 50000
    # Each element of total_train is a tuple of: (a) input vector of length 784
    # and (b) the corresponding one-hot encoded label of length 10
    # Similarly, total_test is an array of length 10000
    shuffle(total_train)
    train = total_train[:1000]
    shuffle(total_test)
    test = total_test[:1000]
    predictions = []
    test_predictions = []
    for i in range(len(train)):
        # Feed forward
        x, t = train[i][0], train[i][1]
        z1 = np.dot(Theta1, x) + b1
        a1 = sigmoid(z1)
        z2 = np.dot(Theta2, a1) + b2
        a2 = sigmoid(z2)
        z3 = np.dot(Theta3, a2) + b3
        y = softmax(z3)
        # Is prediction == target?
        predictions.append(np.argmax(y) == np.argmax(t))

        # Negative log probability cost function
        cost = -t * np.log(y)

        # Backpropagation
        delta3 = (y - t) * softmax_prime(z3)
        dTheta3 = np.outer(delta3, a2)
        db3 = delta3

        delta2 = np.dot(Theta3.T, delta3) * sigmoid_prime(z2)
        dTheta2 = np.outer(delta2, a1)
        db2 = delta2

        delta1 = np.dot(Theta2.T, delta2) * sigmoid_prime(z1)
        dTheta1 = np.outer(delta1, x)
        db1 = delta1

        # Update weights
        Theta1 -= learning_rate * dTheta1
        b1 -= learning_rate * db1
        Theta2 -= learning_rate * dTheta2
        b2 -= learning_rate * db2
        Theta3 -= learning_rate * dTheta3
        b3 -= learning_rate * db3

    if j % 10 == 0:
        m = len(predictions)
        performance = sum(predictions)/m
        print('Epoch:', j, 'Train performance:', performance)

    # Test accuracy on test data
    for i in range(len(test)):
        # Feed forward
        x, t = test[i][0], test[i][1]
        z1 = np.dot(Theta1, x) + b1
        a1 = sigmoid(z1)
        z2 = np.dot(Theta2, a1) + b2
        a2 = sigmoid(z2)
        z3 = np.dot(Theta3, a2) + b3
        y = softmax(z3)
        # Is prediction == target?
        test_predictions.append(np.argmax(y) == np.argmax(t))

    m = len(test_predictions)
    performance = sum(test_predictions)/m
    print('Epoch:', j, 'Test performance:', performance)
```

Output (Every 10 epochs):

```
Epoch: 0 Train performance: 0.121
Epoch: 0 Test performance: 0.146
Epoch: 10 Train performance: 0.37
Epoch: 10 Test performance: 0.359
Epoch: 20 Train performance: 0.41
Epoch: 20 Test performance: 0.433
Epoch: 30 Train performance: 0.534
Epoch: 30 Test performance: 0.52
Epoch: 40 Train performance: 0.607
Epoch: 40 Test performance: 0.601
Epoch: 50 Train performance: 0.651
Epoch: 50 Test performance: 0.669
Epoch: 60 Train performance: 0.71
Epoch: 60 Test performance: 0.711
Epoch: 70 Train performance: 0.719
Epoch: 70 Test performance: 0.694
Epoch: 80 Train performance: 0.75
Epoch: 80 Test performance: 0.752
Epoch: 90 Train performance: 0.76
Epoch: 90 Test performance: 0.758
Epoch: 100 Train performance: 0.766
Epoch: 100 Test performance: 0.769
```

But when I introduce **[Dropout](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rsalakhu/papers/srivastava14a.pdf)** regularization scheme, my network breaks. My code updates for dropout are:

```
dropout_prob = 0.5

# Feed forward
x, t = train[i][0], train[i][1]
z1 = np.dot(Theta1, x) + b1
a1 = sigmoid(z1)
mask1 = np.random.random(len(z1))
mask1 = mask1 < dropout_prob
a1 *= mask1
z2 = np.dot(Theta2, a1) + b2
a2 = sigmoid(z2)
mask2 = np.random.random(len(z2))
mask2 = mask2 < dropout_prob
a2 *= mask2
z3 = np.dot(Theta3, a2) + b3
y = softmax(z3)

# Backpropagation
delta3 = (y - t) * softmax_prime(z3)
dTheta3 = np.outer(delta3, a2)
db3 = delta3 * 1

delta2 = np.dot(Theta3.T, delta3) * sigmoid_prime(z2)
dTheta2 = np.outer(delta2, a1)
db2 = delta2 * 1

delta1 = np.dot(Theta2.T, delta2) * sigmoid_prime(z1)
dTheta1 = np.outer(delta1, x)
db1 = delta1 * 1
```

The performance stays at around `0.1` (10%).

Any pointers on where I'm going wrong is much appreciated.

Comment: 50% dropout is way too much for such a small network.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Tried with `dropout_prob = 0.9` and a smaller learning rate of 0.005, but not much improvement. Now the accuracy is around 20%, but almost constant. I tried plotting the `costs` vs `epochs`, and [this](https://i.imgur.com/pF2cCGI.png) is what I see. (When I set `dropout_prob = 1`, it works the same as without dropout, and accuracy rises as expected.)

Comment: What do you mean by 'my network breaks'? One thought; did you change the gradient descent update to include the `dropout_prob`?

Comment: Did you turn off dropout at test time?

Comment: @jonnybazookatone your comment made me go through Hinton's paper again, where it says "dropout net should typically use 10-100 times the learning rate that was optimal for a standard neural net". 0.03 seemed an ideal learning rate for my net without dropout, and my net trained up to [15% error rate](https://i.imgur.com/NWi6mnC.png). I increased the learning rate when I used Dropout, but lowest error was still [~80%](https://i.imgur.com/qeY4wxV.png). Also note that I've tried training it with 5 times more epochs than without dropout.

Comment: @Imran [yes I did](https://i.imgur.com/pMv0ll0.png). Also multiplied the activation of nodes with `dropout_prob`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a major issue in your implementation of dropout, because you're **not scaling the activations** on test time. Here's the quote from the [great CS231n tutorial](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/):

> Crucially, note that in the `predict` function we are not dropping anymore, but we are performing a scaling of both hidden layer outputs by `p`.
>
> This is important because at test time all neurons see all their
>   inputs, so we want the outputs of neurons at test time to be identical
>   to their expected outputs at training time. For example, in case of
>   `p=0.5`, the neurons must halve their outputs at test time to have
>   the same output as they had during training time (in expectation).
>
> To see this, consider an output of a neuron `x` (before dropout). With
>   dropout, the expected output from this neuron will become
>   `px+(1−p)0`, because the neuron’s output will be set to zero
>   with probability `1−p`. At test time, when we keep the neuron always
>   active, we must adjust `x→px` to keep the same expected output.
>
> It can also be shown that performing this attenuation at test time can be
>   related to the process of iterating over all the possible binary masks
>   (and therefore all the exponentially many sub-networks) and computing
>   their ensemble prediction.

The most common solution is to use an **inverted dropout**, which performs the scaling at train time, leaving the forward pass at test time untouched. This is how it looks like in code:

```py
mask1 = (mask1 < dropout_prob) / dropout_prob
...
mask2 = (mask2 < dropout_prob) / dropout_prob
...
```

Comment: I [_have_](https://i.imgur.com/pMv0ll0.png) scaled the activations during test time, as mentioned in comments above. I tried inverted dropout too as you suggested, but still the network doesn't seem to train. [Here](https://gist.github.com/IshwarBhat/869a12b3a1f50aa78b382f178968c6ae) is the full code.